# How to check if a Java derived type is part of the current call stack?

Tags: java

I am having some troubles finding out if a derived class type is part of a call stack.

Let's say I have 2 classes `Base` and `Derived`:

```
class Base {
    public void foo() {
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

}
```

and I have an instance of `Derived`, and I call the method `foo()` on it

```
Base d = new Derived();
d.foo();
```

and somewhere down the call stack, I want to know if the current call stack contains the class `Derived`

The first thing I think of is using

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

as described in

[How to check if a Java Class is part of the current stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414782/how-to-check-if-a-java-class-is-part-of-the-current-stack-trace)

However, this only gives me the `Base` type in the stack trace, not `Derived`, as the stack trace would look something like this:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1336)
    at x.x.x.x.Base.foo(Base.java:1234)
    at...
```

How can I check for `Derived` in this case in the call stack?

**Edit**: I should clarify that I am more interested in finding out that there is an object `d` of type `Derived` in the call stack, and not that I'm interested in finding out that it was `Derived` or `Base` that the method `foo()` came from

Comment: You can use global `ThreadLocal`, set it at `foo` entry and clean upon exit from `foo`.

Comment: Analyzing the stack to find out of which class a method has been called can be misleading. What if implementation of `foo()` in `Derived` class contained `super.foo()`?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I should clarify that I am more interested in finding out that there is an object `d` of type `Derived` in the call stack, not that I'm interested in finding out that it was `Derived` or `Base` that the method `foo()` came from

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have the object, you must create a list of `Derived.class` plus all its ancestor classes. And check the stacktrace for one of these classes.

However the case becomes a bit more complicated for anonymous & embedded classes.

Comment: I need to check for existence of `Derived` object specifically, and checking for `Derived`'s ancestor classes won't work if those ancestors also have other subclasses other than `Derived`

Comment: That is true. Also the object instance is unknown. A `Derived.f()`could call a `Derived.g()` on an _other_ object and so forth. Only a **debugger** might tackle this kind of problems. Maybe you want AOP, aspect oriented programming.

Comment: I was hoping there's some reflection magic that can help with this.